# Set header title to a xamdatagrid?

Tags: wpf, header, title, xamdatagrid

I am trying to set the header title of a xamdatagrid . Most of the solutions provided explains about setting header at a column . But I need header at the top of grid. [xamdatagrid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpRr0.png)

Comment: Hi, i'm not sure this is even possible but xaml is rich so tryp putting your DataGrid into a GroupBox that should do the trick

Comment: @XimazeC The trick worked , it was not exactly what I was looking for though. I liked the idea of putting it in a groupbox and show the header text. Thank You.